# Config file for importing data from multiple couchdb databases Logstash

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, couchdb, logstash

We are storing our data types in each of its database in couchdb. What sort of format will the config file have to import data from multiple databases? Or do I need to have multiple config files for importing data from each database to an index. Will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We use a single config file for multiple databases.

It's not perfect, but functional for now.

Currently looks like:

```
input { 
  couchdb_changes {
    sequence_path => "db1.seq"
    db => "db1"
    host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    username => "xxx"
    password => "xxx"
    add_field => {
       "organization" => "db1"
    }
  }
  couchdb_changes {
    sequence_path => "db2.seq"
    db => "db2"
    host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    username => "xxx"
    password => "xxx"
    add_field => {
       "organization" => "db2"
    }
  }
} 

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "_attachments" ]
  }
}

output { 
  stdout { codec => rubydebug } 

  elasticsearch { 
    cluster => "cluster0"
    host => ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"] 
    protocol => "http" 
    index => "%{[organization]}" 
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  } 
}
```